# How to specify an iterator in the volume path when using docker-compose to scale up service?

Tags: docker, scale, docker-compose, volume, docker-swarm

**Background:** I'm using docker-compose in order to place a tomcat service into a docker swarm cluster but I'm presently struggling with how I would approach the logging directory given that I want to scale the service up yet retain the uniqueness of the logging directory.

Consider the (obviously) made up docker-compose which simply starts tomcat and mounts a logging filesystem in which to capture the logs.

`version: '2'
  services:
    tomcat:
      image: "tomcat:latest"
      hostname: tomcat-example
      command: /start.sh
      volumes:
        - "/data/container/tomcat/logs:/opt/tomcat/logs,z"`

Versions

- docker 1.11
- docker-compose 1.7.1
- API version 1.21

**Problem:** I'm looking to understand how I would approach inserting a variable into the 'volume' log path so that the log directory is unique for each instance of the scaled service

say,

```
volumes:
    - "/data/container/tomcat/${container_name}/logs:/opt/tomcat/logs,z"
```

I see that based on project name (or directory I'm in) the container name is actually known, so could I use this ?

eg, setting the project name to 'tomcat' and running `docker-compose scale tomcat=2` I would see the following containers.

- *hostname*/tomcat_1
- *hostname*/tomcat_2

So is there any way I could leverage this as a variable in the logging volume, Other suggestions or approaches welcome. I realise that I could just specify a relative path and let the container_id take care of this, but now if I attach splunk or logstash to the logging devices I'd need to know which ones are indeed logging devices as opposed to the base containers f/s. However Ideally I'm looking use a specific absolute path here.

Thanks in advance dockers!
R.

Comment: I think a better approach is to output container logs to stdout and use Docker's logging drivers to later parse them. Splunk is on the list here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/. Also, `docker-compose logs` would aggregate your logs for you with the container name and number on prepended in each log entry.

Comment: I would second @saada's reco. I use syslog drive to logstash and it works great. It makes scaling and adding services easy to manage.

Answer (score 1):

You should really NOT log to the filesystem, and use a specialized log management tool like graylog/logstash/splunk/... instead. Either configure your logging framework in Tomcat with a specific appender, or log to sysout and configure a logging driver in Docker to redirect your logs to the external destination.

This said, if you really want to go the filesystem way, simply use a regular unnamed volume, and then call `docker inspect` on your container to find the volume's path on the filesystem :

```
[...snip...]
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Type": "volume",
        "Name": "b8c...SomeHash...48d6e",
        "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/b8c...SomeHash...48d6e/_data",
        "Destination": "/opt/tomcat/logs",
[...snip...]
```

If you want to have nice-looking names in a specific location, use a script to create symlinks.

Yet, I'm still doubtfull on this solution, especially in a multi-host swarm context. Logging to an external, specialized service is the way to go in your use case.