# Scaling up persistent named volumes in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to scale using docker-compose to create multiple nodes of [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html). I was using a named container for the first node but when scaling up these different nodes were all using the same volume which led to read-write conflicts.

Then I tried using anonymous volumes, but I've read that these are [disregarded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39013222/data-container-with-named-or-anonymous-volumes-conceptual-problems-discuss). And when I run `docker-compose down` and then `up`, the existing anonymous volumes are not reused and instead new ones are created.

**So my question is, how can I scale up containers with separate persistent volumes?**

In [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38504328/how-to-specify-an-iterator-in-the-volume-path-when-using-docker-compose-to-scale) something similar is being asked, but hasn't been answered yet.

For reasons of complexity I am not yet prepared to run in swarm mode.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @eugenevd, unfortunately not.. I ended up letting several scaled containers use the same named volume

Comment: that impliest that you can set elasticsearch nodes to share the same data directory? I get lock related errors when the 2nd node starts up

Comment: my data/nodes directory has a separate subdirectory for every instance. that seems to happen automatically when I scale ES (5.x)

Comment: When working with Kubernetes there is a [statefulset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) which enables scaling.

Comment: There's this github issue, with not much traction: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4579